# Topology, Hausdorff and Fréchet space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Solving a problem I came to an apparent contradiction. The problem is the following:

*Let $X$ be a set and $p\in X$. We consider the following topology on $X$*

$\tau_p = \{ A \subseteq X: p \notin A \} \cup \{ B \subseteq X : X \setminus B$ is finite$ \} $

*Is $(X,\tau_p)$ Fréchet or Hausdorff?*

I know that a set $X$ is Fréchet if and only if every point set is closed. However, if $X$ has more than one element, say $a$, then $\{a\}$ is open, since $p \notin \{a\}$. But I've successfully shown that $X$ is Hausdorff, which should imply that $X$ is Fréchet.

I'm so confused about this.

Comment: $T_{1}$ does not imply Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of finite set $X$, the cofinite topology and the discrete topology coincidies and hence each singleton is closed and open.

In case $X$ is infinite.

Then $X\setminus\{p\}$ is open hence $\{p\}$ is closed.

and for $p\neq a$.

$X\setminus (X\setminus\{a\})=\{a\}$ is finite and hence $X\setminus\{a\}$ is open and hence $\{a\}$ is closed.

Hence $X$ is Frechet.

Now for $x,y\in X$ and $x\neq y$ .

If one of $x$ or $y$ is $p$ say $x=p$.

Then $\{y\}$ is open And $X\setminus \{y\}$ is an open set such that $p\in X\setminus \{y\}$ and both are disjoint.

If $x\neq p$ and $y\neq p$ .

Then $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are two open disjoint sets.

Then $X$ is Hausdorff.